# C++ system() causes "Text file busy" error

Tags: c++, bash

I need to execute multiple times a FORTRAN program, that requires the user to insert 4 numeric values each time.
I found a solution to make this automatically with a Python script...this script basically creates at each iteration a .sh file containing the following lines (a.out is the name of the FORTRAN program I have to execute automatically)

```
./a.out<<EOF
param01
param02
param03
param04
EOF
```

makes it executable, and executes it.

So, I'm trying to do the same in C++...I wrote something like

```
int main()
{

long double mass[3] = {1.e+10,3.16e+10,1.0e+11};
double tau[3] = {0.5,0.424,0.4};
double nu[3] = {03.0,4.682,10.0};
long double Reff[3] = {1.0e+3,1.481e+3,3.0e+3};
int temp=0;



for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
    ofstream outfile("shcommand.sh");
    outfile << "./a.out<<EOF" << endl << mass[i] << endl << nu[i] << endl << Reff[i] << endl << tau[i] << endl << "EOF" << endl;
    temp=system("chmod +x shcommand.sh");
    temp=system("./shcommand.sh");
    }

return 0;   

}
```

but when I run my C++ program, I get the following error message

```
sh: 1: ./shcommand.sh: Text file busy
sh: 1: ./shcommand.sh: Text file busy
sh: 1: ./shcommand.sh: Text file busy
```

Has it something to do with the C++ program trying to modify the .sh file before the previous iteration is finished?
I looked online, and I seemed to understand the system() command onlyreturns after the command has been completed...

Comment: Why do you never use the result of `system`? You have no error checking.

Comment: did you close the file before you try to run it? (eg. outfile.close() )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to run an open file, which isn't such a good idea. Close it before `chmod`ding/running it:

```
for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
{
    {
        ofstream outfile("shcommand.sh");
        outfile << "./a.out<<EOF" << endl << mass[i] << endl << nu[i] << endl << Reff[i] << endl << tau[i] << endl << "EOF" << endl;
        // the file is closed when outfile goes out of scope
    }
    temp=system("chmod +x shcommand.sh");
    temp=system("./shcommand.sh");
}
```

Incidentally, all this shell mess can be avoided by writing straight to the standard input of your program (e.g. with `popen`):

```
for (int i=0; i<3; ++i) {
    FILE *fd = popen("./a.out", "w");
    assert(fd!=NULL); // do proper error handling...
    fprintf(fd, "%Lf\n%f\n%Lf\n%f\n", mass[i], nu[i], Reff[i], tau[i]);
    fclose(fd);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems because the shell cannot read the script because it is still opened by your program.

Try adding `outfile.close();` before calling `system()`.